# When i run the code it always give a 0 output for division?

Tags: c

I am solving the hacker rank problem plus minus and encountered the problem where the division gives 0.0000

```
int main()
{
    int array_size;
    printf("Enter the size of array: \n");
    scanf("%d",&array_size);

    int array [array_size];
    for(int i=0;i<array_size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    int positive=0;
    int negative=0;
    int zero=0;
    for(int i =0; i<array_size;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<0)
        {
            negative++;
        }
        if(array[i]>0)
        {
            positive++;
        }
        if(array[i]=0)
        {
            zero++;
        }
    }
    float x = positive / array_size;
    float y = negative / array_size;
    float z = zero / array_size;
    printf("%lf \n",x);
    printf("%lf \n",y);
    printf("%lf \n",z);

    return 1;

}
```

Actual Result:- 
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000

Expected Result:-
The actual divisions...

Comment: `int array_size;`, `int positive` ==> `positive / array_size` is integer division. Try `(double)positive / array_size`

Comment: `if( array[i]=0)` should read `if( array[i]==0)`.  Note the `==`. A single `=` is an assignment.

Comment: `if(array[i]=0)` You probably mean `if(array[i]==0)`

Comment: Furthermore, I think it's more efficient to use if ... else if ...

Comment: If I were you, I would print out the array size and the contents of the array before trying to count the number of positive and negative numbers. You want to make sure you have read in the data correctly before trying to process it.